# Как проверить список стеков

Tags: java, arraylist

Доброго времени суток!

Извиняюсь за такой примитивный вопрос, ответ на который наверняка лежит на поверхности.

Мне надо проверить что список не пустой. Как сделать проверку списка?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Использовать стандартную функцию

`list` - ваш лист

```
if (list.isEmpty()) {
     // Пустой
    } else {
     // Не пустой
    }
```

Впредь, перед тем как задавать подобные вопросы:

- Загуглите сам вопрос.
- Почитайте документацию или какой нибудь онлайн справочник языка.
- Если работаете в IDE нажатием ctrl + пробел посмотрите подсказки (если не сработало посмотрите в настройках IDE как настроить подсказки).
- Изучите функции и методы объекта(класса, коллекции) с которым работаете.
- Если ничего не помогло то тогда уже можно задавать вопросы сюда.

Вопрос слишком элементарный, ответ на который можно найти везде.